# Taking MySQL data and outputting as nested JSON via PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to export data from my database in a format that can be used by a third party service. Getting data from a MySQL DB into JSON is pretty trivial. I am currently using the following for testing, although it's not my full dataset.

```
$result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM Contracts LIMIT 3");

  $dbdata = array();

  while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {

    $rowarray['id'] = $row['ContractID'];
    $rowarray['title'] = $row['Service_Name'];
    $rowarray['currency'] = 'GBP';
    $rowarray['amountAppliedFor'] = $row['Sum_Requested'];
    $rowarray['amountAwarded'] = $row['Sum_Approved'];
    $rowarray['awardDate'] = $row['Decision_Date'];
    $rowarray['recipientOrganization'] = $row['Provider'];

    $dbdata[]=$rowarray;

  }

  echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

And that easily outputs:

```
[ 

   { 

      "id":"147",
      "title":"Whatever",
      "currency":"GBP",
      "amountAppliedFor":"5000.00",
      "amountAwarded":"5000.00",
      "awardDate":"2019-07-14",
      "recipientOrganization":"32"
   },
   { 

      "id":"146",
      "title":"Test",
      "currency":"GBP",
      "amountAppliedFor":"1000.00",
      "amountAwarded":"0.00",
      "awardDate":"2019-07-04",
      "recipientOrganization":"32"
   },
   { 

      "id":"144",
      "title":"Test",
      "currency":"GBP",
      "amountAppliedFor":"15000.00",
      "amountAwarded":"15000.00",
      "awardDate":"0000-00-00",
      "recipientOrganization":"32"
   }
]
```

Easy enough.

But the schema I'm trying to create looks something like:

```
{
  "grants" : [ {
    "id" : "",
    "recipientOrganization" : [ {
      "id" : "",
      "companyNumber" : "",
      "charityNumber" : "",
      "name" : "",
    } ],
    "fundingOrganization" : [ {
      "id" : "",
      "name" : ""
    } ],

    "title" : "",
    "currency" : "",
    "amountAwarded" : "" }]
}
```

I'm not clear how to structure the data, with objects etc. At the moment I'm just outputting flat JSON. Am I meant to use something like:

`json_encode($dbdata, array(...));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your structure should be

```
  while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {

    $rowarray['id'] = $row['ContractID'];
    $rowarray['recipientOrganization'] = array(
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "companyNumber" => $row['companyNumber'],
         "charityNumber" => $row['charityNumber'],
         "name" => $row['name']
    );
    $rowarray['fundingOrganization'] = array(
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "name" => $row['name']
    );

    $rowarray['title'] = $row['Service_Name'];
    $rowarray['currency'] = 'GBP';
    //$rowarray['amountAppliedFor'] = $row['Sum_Requested'];
    $rowarray['amountAwarded'] = $row['Sum_Approved'];
    //$rowarray['awardDate'] = $row['Decision_Date'];



    $dbdata['grants'][] = $rowarray;

  }
```

Also one tip I like to do is throw the json into phpsandbox and convert it to an array to see the structure.  Like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5dec82db9310edc74e34261082641a64fc8b022d